# simple route defined by Route::view gives an error "Route not defined", when defined using Route::name it works well

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

The case is very simple, but I found no references to it:

1. I have a blade `\front\about`
2. I have a line in `layout.blade.php`:
   `<li {{ currentRoute('about') }}><a href="{{route('about')}}">About Us</a></li>`

When I define a route in web.routes as

`Route::view('/about', 'front.about');`

it fails on:

```
Route [about] not defined. (View: ....\resources\views\front\layout.blade.php)
```

Everything works well when I define the route via

`Route::name('about')->get('about',function() { return View::make('front.about');});`

Except, it (obviously) fails on `$ php artisan route:cache`, since being closure

`Unable to prepare route [about] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

Please help to resolve the case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the route a name:

```
Route::view('/about', 'front.about')->name('about');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexey. Please notice that `route()` method requires `router name` as parameter but actually you didn't define router name in `web.router`.  you did : `Route::view('/about', 'front.about');` that doesn't have router name.

so it should be like this:

```
Route::view('/about', 'front.about')->name('about');
```

or use `url()` method that requires slug as parameter instead

```
a href="{{url('about')}}">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I missed it.